# Why IllegalArgumentException "interface is not a protocol" when importing a Clojure protocol?

Tags: clojure, namespaces, protocols

I followed Cursive's suggestion to *Import class* when using `extend-protocol` in a different namespace to the one where `defprotocol` occurred.

```clj
(ns the.first)
(defprotocol AProtocol
  (method [this]))

(ns the.second
  (:import (the.first AProtocol)) ; <= Cursive suggested this...
(extend-protocol AProtocol ; <= ...because this wasn't in scope.
  AType
  (method [this] ...))
```

I tore my hair out a little at the `IllegalArgumentException: interface the.first.AProtocol is not a protocol`.

Answer (score 2):

Then I realised I should have ignored the IDE's hint, and `:require`d the protocol (and methods, for convenience).

```clj
(ns the.second
  (:require [the.first :refer [AProtocol amethod]]))
```

Only obvious in retrospect.